# Is there a way to create a custom installer package to do batch installs of a bunch of programs at once?

Tags: windows, batch, scripting, packages, installation

Basically I want to create a file which will automatically install a bunch of files without having to manually install each of them (i.e. Flash, Adobe Reader, MS Office, etc.).

I'm guessing the easiest way to do this would be to create a batch file but I don't have much experience with the scripting side of things.

I remember seeing a website at one point that would do this sort of thing for you but I'm not sure if that could be used offline or not.

Thanks in advance...just looking to make things a bit more streamlined on new builds without the costs associated with imaging software.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look at something like http://wpkg.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write batch files, usually each line looks something like:
`msiexec msifile.msi /q TRANSFORMS=transform.mst`
You can use Orca to create MST files, it takes a bit of getting used to though (MSTs change the default properties of the MSI installer file). You can get Orca from MS in the [Win SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=162443). MS has [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx) for it. But you'll find the best information at [AppDeploy.com](http://www.appdeploy.com/).

If it's not an MSI file, commonly you can type `setup.exe /?` to get the command line switches. Also the `/q` and `/a` are pretty widely used for 'quiet' or 'automated' installs.